# HPE UFT - UFTBatchRunnerCMD.exe not working

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

When I try to run UFTBatchRunnerCMD.exe with the following command on cmd:
"UFTBatchRunnerCMD.exe -source "C:\MyTestPath". 

After I execute it on cmd, even with administrative rights, it gives me the following error:

> Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID
>   {2B9B8E92-EBAA-44AF-A23C-9FBD08EAFA54} from the IClassFactory failed
>   due to the following error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL)). QTP is not launched. Run results can be
>   found at ''

Comment: Are you trying to run this test on your local machine or remotely?

Comment: I tried both ways.